# email to api service? does it exist?

Tags: api, email

Is there any service that receives emails users send to me, parse the content and call my API?

I would do it myself but don't want to mess with mailservers, cronjobs, etc

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google App Engine has a [mail API](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/mail/receivingmail.html) built in, that seems very simple to use, just forward the email to string@appid.appspotmail.com

I will use that, calling the API of my app hosted in heroku.

Thanks Chris for your answer, it is very good to know that a simple email framework exists!

Answer (score 1):

I approached this problem a week or so ago whilst trying to provide one of our developers to not write something.  There is nothing out of the box or hosted that I've found.

The nearest thing I've seen is a DIY SMTP framework in Python which is quite powerful (Lamson).  It allows you to receive email, process it and call external services or store the message content.

http://lamsonproject.org/

Hope this helps.

Comment: good one, thanks Chris. However Im trying to avoid messing with server configuration etc. Lamson looks very very interesting though.

Comment: Yeah I'd like to avoid the same thing if possible ideally.  I'll keep an eye on this thread to see if anything happens.

Answer (score 0):

SendGrid.com also offers this service. http://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Webhooks/parse.html